# Getting Error: Unable to install package. (e800004b) in dephi while trying to run in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update 2 Trail Version for developing iOS mobile application. And I'm using Mac book pro with the Mac OS sierra and using Xcode 8.1 and having the iPhoneSimulator 10.1 SDK & iPhone10.1 SDK in my windows machine. And having iphone 5s with OS 10.1.

When I'm trying to run the app in mobile, I'm getting  **Unable to install package. (e800004b).**  error.

Also when I'm trying to use simulator, the Simulators are not shown in the Target node.

If I'm using Xcode 7.3.1, I'm able to run the app in simulator. Please help me to run the app in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Your message is not very clear. Are we talking about a DPK package?
If yes, then:

**Solution** (Easy way (if you are lucky))

1. Right-click your project (DPK) and choose 'Clean'
2. Rebuild your project.

If this is not working, you have to do it **the hard way**:

1. Close IDE.
2. Go to the BPL/DCP folder and delete all BPLs/DCPs/BPIs related to this package of yours.
3. Start IDE, load your DPK file and build from zero (and install the Design-time packages)

This will make the problem go away.

> c:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\Bpl
> c:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\Dcp\

**Still errors?**
The error msg shows that you might have an error in your package. If your package is a design-time package, then it makes sense.
Start a second instance of the IDE and debug the package.